# Getting values of multiple classes at once

Tags: php

I just started a PHP course and we have to try and code different elements of a checkout system and I made a class for products and different products you could buy each with a price and a barcode. I can get the individual value of each product to show on the screen, but I want to create a basket that can have multiple items in it and display them on the screen. What would be the best way to do this?

```
<?php


class product {

    public $price;
    public $barCode;

    public function __construct($price, $barCode)
    {
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->barCode = $barCode; 
    }

    public function showInfo()
    {
        echo $this->price;
        echo $this->barCode;
    }
}



class Milk extends product 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(2, 445662);
    }
}

class Bread extends product 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(5, 454452);
    }
}

class Beer extends product 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(1, 445242);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to check out [Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372644/what-is-the-purpose-of-interfaces-in-php). Apart from that "How best to do something" tends to bring opinionated answers, please see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Are you possibly also talking about keeping track of this using sessions or cookies?

Comment: if you going to use OOP to make basket, don't make php classes for the products but instead make the cart, i.e `$cart->addItem([line-item-data])`, removeItem, clearItems, getTotalPrice.. etc